# R - lapply() Returning Null Values in Data Frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame, **util_final** with a column, *utilization_Ratio* I would like to use to assign categorical values.

The data frame has the following structure:

```
$ Patient_ID       : Factor w/ 3242 levels "0000001C-89D2-40FF-868D-8E1B4C8C9114",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ OP               : num  1 11 2 1 5 6 12 8 10 6 ...
 $ IP               : num  2 0 0 1 1 3 4 5 0 3 ...
 $ Total            : num  3 11 2 2 6 9 16 13 10 9 ...
 $ utilization_Ratio: num  0.667 0 0 0.5 0.167 ...
```

I've created this function to define the aforementioned categorical values:

```
assign_risk_factor=function(x) {
  for(i in util_final$utilization_Ratio) {
    if(i<0.33) {
      print("Low")
    } else if(i>0.67) {
      print("High")
    } else {
      print("Medium")
    }
  } 
}
```

I then tried to use lapply() to connect the function with the data frame, inserting the categorical variable defined in the function in a new column in the data frame:

```
util_final$Risk_Factor=lapply(util_final$utilization_Ratio,assign_risk_factor)
```

That, indeed, creates the new column, but it simply inserts a "NULL" in each row of the column, like so:

```
Patient_ID OP IP Total utilization_Ratio Risk_Factor
0000001C-89D2-40FF-868D-8E1B4C8C9114 0000001C-89D2-40FF-868D-8E1B4C8C9114  1  2     3         0.6666667        NULL
001B8544-508E-4CBE-A40A-EAAD97E541BE 001B8544-508E-4CBE-A40A-EAAD97E541BE 11  0    11         0.0000000        NULL
00336A6F-93D8-42F6-B2E5-A1EF12C2BD75 00336A6F-93D8-42F6-B2E5-A1EF12C2BD75  2  0     2         0.0000000        NULL
0039B0C1-E84F-4B90-AD9B-985C9F39ABD1 0039B0C1-E84F-4B90-AD9B-985C9F39ABD1  1  1     2         0.5000000        NULL
003E8473-C645-4AF2-B48A-86BE76188CC5 003E8473-C645-4AF2-B48A-86BE76188CC5  5  1     6         0.1666667        NULL
00765CEF-B05C-471F-B91F-8154E6158486 00765CEF-B05C-471F-B91F-8154E6158486  6  3     9         0.3333333        NULL
```

The part that really confuses me: when I run the lapply() function, the console seems to show the categorical variables producing as expected (in other words, suggesting the For Loop I created works).  However, again, the resulting new column of my data frame only contains NULL's.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `print` (this is for display purpose). Instead, assign `"Low"`, `"High"` and `"Medium"` to a variable, then `return()` this variable at the end of your function `assign_risk_factor`.

Comment: You are actually running two loops: one with lapply for every value of `util_final$utilization_Ratio` and another for-loop that repeats that process every time you call `assign_risk_factor`. I cannot tell what the goal of the effort is. It's generally unwise to say you are having difficulties when the goal of the effort has not been described clearly in natural language.

Comment: Thank you, both!  Loops remain a relatively new concept for me in R, so you can see I have a lot to learn about them.

Answer (score 3):

You function doesn't actually return anything. Printing isn't the same as returning and you're not building any sort of vector in your for loop. Plus, the `cut()` function can do this type of splitting for you. How about

```
util_final$Risk_Factor <- cut(util_final$utilization_Ratio, 
    breaks = c(-Inf, .33, .67, Inf), 
    labels = c("Low","Medium","High"))
```

Comment: Actually print methods generally have two consequences: one is the output to the console but the other is to return a value.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much!  When I learned how to build loops, the examples contained print(), so I approached this from that reference point.